# APIM Error: cURL DELETE command on an API returns a Runtime Error

Tags: curl, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

My API has a DSS service as a backend and has associated resources for GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE operations. However when I issue a DELETE operation on the service, even though at the backend it happened successfully, APIM returns a runtime error:

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer 356bcb27f82c849e383d3765e0ccce" -X DELETE http://localhost:8280/fte/1.0/users/105/vacations/13
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying localhost...
* Connected localhost (localhost) port 8280 (#0)
> DELETE /fte/1.0/users/105/vacations/13 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.36.0
> Host: localhost:8280
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer 356bcb27f82c849e383d3765e0ccce
>
< HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type
< Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Tue, 09 Sep 2014 07:38:00 GMT
* Server WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP is not blacklisted
< Server: WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>0</am:code><am:type>Status report</am:type><am:message>Runtime Error</am:message><am:description>Error while building message</am:description></am:fault>[
```

How can I prevent this kind of error? Do I need an output message from the backend service so that it does not display this runtime error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because your backend service does not respond with a message body. Rather it sends only HTTP status code. APIManager tries to build message from that empty payload. To prevent you can open your api configuration(repository/deploymnet/server/synapse-config/default/api)
and for DELETE operation, before sending to backend make it as one-way message by setting OUT_ONLY property.

```
<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
```

Make sure you set that property only for DELETE operation. If other operations return any response body then this property will affect them.

Comment: thank you for the response, but based on my api config I don't have a specific setting for delete operation here is the resouce line from the api ` <resource methods="POST GET DELETE OPTIONS PUT" url-mapping="/*">` and as you have said putting that property incorrectly would affect the response body of other operations. Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: Within insequence check for the HTTP methodis DELETE then set that OUT_ONLY property (yes, this is bit custom mediaton logic you need to do) You can use custom sequence option for this too. Please refer this document: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Adding+Mediation+Extensions

Comment: great thanks! I was thinking of a custom mediation too as that is the only way to set the property for the delete operation. Thank you very much for the help!